# For Next loop error: Option Strict On disallows late binding

Tags: vb.net, excel-interop

I have the following code which produces an error:

```
Option Strict On
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class Form1
Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Book1.xlsx")
    xlApp.Visible = True
    For i = 1 To xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Count
        xlWorkBook.Worksheets(i).Visible = True
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you first reference to the `Worksheets` using `xlWorkSheet` and then set the `.Visible` property on that? (Not sure if you can do that but seems like something you possible can).

Comment: You are just stating a fact.  You declared an xlWorkSheet variable, consider using it.  Use CType() to cast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I guess* what you are after is:

```
Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Book1.xlsx")
    xlApp.Visible = True
    For i = 1 To xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Count
        xlWorkSheet = CType(xlWorkBook.Worksheets(i), Excel.Worksheet)
        xlWorkSheet.Visible = Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVisible

        'If you don't want to make use of xlWorkSheet you can use this:
        'CType(xlWorkBook.Sheets(i), Excel.Worksheet).Visible = Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetHidden
    Next
End Sub
```

You should always look at using the object as this will provide the correct usage of the object's properties. Note the change of `Visible = True` to `Visible = Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVisible`

Comment: How about this `CType(xlWorkBook.Sheets(i), Excel.Worksheet).Visible = CType(True, Excel.XlSheetVisibility)`

Comment: @SamSamuel that isn't required. If you want to pop onto one line just `CType(xlWorkBook.Sheets(i), Excel.Worksheet).Visible = Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVisible` will work fine. I broke it up into two to show the use of the object.